# Вывести на экран вектор с диапазоном (многопоточность)

Tags: c++

Мне нужно научиться использовать многопоточность при добавлении или удалении значения в векторе. Я создала функцию `CopyDataTo`, чтобы вывести на экран, что  у меня  записано в векторое после операций, и мне нельзя использовать operator[].

```
std::size_t CopyDataTo(T* pOutData, std::size_t firstIndex, std::size_t numData)
{
    std::size_t lastIndex = firstIndex + numData;
    const std::size_t indexAfterLast = std::min(firstIndex + numData, v_.size());
    m_.lock();
    std::copy(v_.begin() + firstIndex, v_.begin() + indexAfterLast, pOutData);
    m_.unlock();
    return *pOutData;
}
private:
   std::vector<T> v_;
```

Теперь я создала две функции и  делаю там добавления и удаления из вектора. В `main` создала  два  потока и записала туда функции.

```
std::vector<int> v1;
void f3()
{
   int i = 9;
   v1.push_back(i);
   v1.back();
}

void f4()
{
   int i = 6;
   v1.push_back(i);
   v1.back();
   v1.pop_back();
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t1(f3);
  std::thread t2(f4);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  int pOutData;
  for(int i = 0; i < v1.Size(); ++i)
  {
    std::cout << v1.CopyDataTo(&pOutData, 0, v1.Size()) << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Теперь я  хочу чтобы, вы мне  помогли. Я Часть кода уже исправила, спасибо Вам,  теперь мне нужно мой код сделать рабочим. И нужна ваша помощь: Оксана у  тебя в  этой строке фигня,  нужно так  делать и т.д. Буду вам благодарна за помощь

UPD:

```
 ThreadSafeVector<int> v1;
 void f3()
 {
    v1.PushBack(5);
    v1.PushBack(9);
 }

 void f4()
 {
    v1.PushBack(2);
    v1.PushBack(1);
 }

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(f3);
    std::thread t2(f4);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

   int* pOutData = new int[v1.Size()];
   size_t size = v1.CopyDataTo(pOutData, 0, v1.Size());
   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      std::cout << pOutData[i] << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: На будущее, запомните, что слова "выдает ошибку" совершенно ничего не говорят о проблеме. Опишите что за ошибка, как ругается компилятор, где именно.  
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы на самом деле пытаетесь заполнить вектор числами от 0 до бесконечности.

Comment: А вы куда хотите скопировать данные? Я в этом `v1.CopyDataTo(&i, 0, v1.Size())` не вижу смысла вообще никакого. В лучшем случае вы затрете переменную-счетчик цикла, в худшем перепишете память в стеке, которая вам не принадлежит.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb а как правильно? я  так  переделала                            
        UPD2  Мне  нужно просто вывести на екран что я  записал. Поэтому я фор использую

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, Правильность зависит от того, что вы хотите сделать. Раз у вас все скомпилировалось, предполагаю, что у вас в `v1` инты. Тогда у меня к вам встречный вопрос, что произойдет если там больше одного числа(`v1.Size()`, например, 42)?

Comment: Хотя нет, я вообще не понимаю что у вас там твориться. Как это `std::vector<int> v1;` и это `v1.CopyDataTo(&i, 0, v1.Size())` компилируются?? У меня для вас совет. Удалите все свои UPD, приведите минимальный компилируемый код с проблемой и напишите что вы хотите сделать. И это не должен быть вопрос, как держать микроскоп, чтобы забивать гвозди. Опишите сразу цель. А люди уже подскажут как правильно это делается

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb передалала как вы казали

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb спасибо за исправления. а что по коду скажете?

Comment: Что вы хотели сказать вызовами `v1.back();`? Что именно они должны сделать?

Answer (score 2):

[`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) работает с итераторами, а не с индексами.

```
std::copy(v.begin() + firstIndex, v.begin() + indexAfterLast, pOutData);
```

Comment: такое выдает: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4996 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, это уже закидоны детища майкрософта. Напишите `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` перед инклюдами

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb написала,  но всеравно кричит Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4996 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, `#pragma warning(disable:4996) `

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb я  так  написала                                                                        #define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable:4996)


#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> и всеравно ошибка: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C4996 'std::copy::_Unchecked_iterators::_Deprecate': Call to 'std::copy' with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++

Comment: помогло  когда  записала в  это в stdafx.h

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, значит самое время принять ответ

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb так я  сначала  записывала перед инклудамы в моем файле,  а нужно  было в  stdafx.h. Буду  знать.  Я сдулала UPD своей програмы. И снова ошибки там вылезли(((

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець Не делайте так, это очень толковое предупреждение. Оно говорит, что передавая в этот метод просто указатель без указания размера буффера, на который он указывает вы создаете угрозу переполнения буффера со всеми вытекающими. Конструкции `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS #pragma warning(disable:4996)` использовать не следует. И использовать сырые указатели тоже.

Comment: @VTT, это единственный переносимый способ подавить это предупреждение. Альтернатива `stdext::checked_array_iterator`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Я высказался в том смысле, что предупреждения не надо подавлять, а надо устранять причину их появления.

Comment: @VTT, как устранить это предупреждение, если надо работать с массивом?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb При работе с `std::array` ничего дополнительно делать не надо, при работе с сырыми указателями (т.е. указатель + размер блока) следует написать `array_view` реализующий требуемые проверки для своих итераторов.

Comment: @VTT, в стандартной библиотеке нет `array_view`. Где его взять-то?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Пока в стандартной библиотеке его нету следует написать самому. Можно взять [черновик стандарта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4512.html) в качестве отправной точки.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::size_t rezult =
```

`size_t` встроенный тип - тот же `unsigned int`, не из пространства std...

```
std::copy(v_.begin() + firstIndex, v_.begin() + indexAfterLast, pOutData);
```

это ошибка, так как copy возвращает итератор записи, а не size_t...
В данном примере он возвратит `T*`

Comment: а как правельно тогда возвращать и записывать в  return?

Comment: я отвечу вам через несколько минут, извените

Comment: @Оксана Волинець, во первых вам уже ответили что нужно возвращать (Croessmah ответил), а если вы хотите присвоить имя, то это имя будет типа T* или auto.   Если ваш  pOutData  есть int*, то вы должны присвоить результат  int* p = copy (... ); return p; Но вы в main() тоже допускаете ошибку, так как вы используете адрес обьекта как указатель, куда вы потенциально хотите записать содержание вектора.  Непонятно вообше чего вы хотите добиваться...

Comment: @ AR Hovsepyan передалала вопрос. Можете посмотреть

Comment: Если на то пошло, то на большинстве систем `size_t` — это `unsigned long`.

Comment: @ Fat-Zer , да,  вы правы - просто  хотел быть кратким,

Comment: Про `size_t` - совершенно не верно. Это не встроенный тип, а typedef имя для какого-то встроенного типа. В заголовочных файлах стандартной библиотеки С++ он объявлен как `std::size_t`. Без `std` он может быть виден тоже, но это не гарантируется.

Comment: @AnT, встроенный тип или  другое имя встроенного типа... разницу не вижу.  size_t   обьявлен в std, но он обьявлен не только в std, и без std он гарантированно виден.  Ведь его цель заключается в том, чтобы четко выразить о намерении хранения размера ( насколько я знаю )

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Нет, не гарантировано. Если включаются С++ заголовки типа `<cstdlib>`, то - именно `std::size_t`, а просто `size_t` может быть виден, а может быть не виден. Это опционально и *не гарантируется*.  Если же включаются С заголовки типа `<stdlib.h>`, то виден будет именно `size_t`, но возможность включения таких С заголовков в С++ код официально является устаревшим (deprecated) свойством языка.

Comment: @ AnT, ок, спасибо за инфу

Comment: @AnT, а в каком пункте стандарта языка написано, что возможность включения C заголовков — устаревшее свойство языка?

Comment: @wololo: "Annex D. Compatibility features" содержит список deprecated свойств языка. "D.5 C standard library headers [depr.c.headers]" (http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.c.headers) Также http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header#C_compatibility_headers

Answer (score 0):

Перегрузите `operator<<` для вашего класса:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ThreadSafeVector<T> &v){
    v.lock();
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, " "));
    v.unlock();
    return os;
}
```

Теперь можете писать так:

```
 std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
```

Я вызвал методы `lock` и `unlock`, не уверен что они есть у вас, если нет, то добавьте, т.к. иначе число элементов вектора может измениться пока работает `std::copy`.

Да я понимаю, что в вопросе было про диапазон. Но я не вижу где бы вам это могло понадобиться, вы все равно пытаетесь вывести все.

Comment: v1.back(); - последние  значение увидеть. return *pOutData; - а как  тут все что есть в pOutData увидеть?    У std::vector нет методов Size и CopyDataTo- size() есть. А CopyDataTo это моя функция

Comment: @ОксанаВолинець, 1)`size` - есть, `Size` - нет. 
2) `CopyDataTo` это ваша функция, но не метод вектора, а вы вызываете ее как метод вектора. 
3) Как вызов `back` помогает вам увидеть что-то? Вы же никак не обрабатываете возвращаемое значение. Но, все эти чудеса возможны только если вы написали специализацию `vector` для `int`. Вы делали это?

Comment: да я свой вектор  написала с основными функциями. Поэтому Size() с  большой  буквы. все я поняла что мне нужно возвращать : return (indexAfterLast - firstIndex) в CopyDataTo

Comment: относительно back то pop_back , я случайно удалила pop_